# Instruments says heap is growing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-management, instruments

I'm running my app in Xcode 4.5 through Instruments with the Allocations profile. This project is non-ARC. Each minute, my app calls the following piece of code. Note that the caller of this method is running in a background thread, and it's surrounded by an NSAutoReleasePool.

```
-(void)saveCurrentlyCachedMinute
{
    NSCalendarUnit units = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *now = [[NSCalendarcurrentCalendar] components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    self.cachedTimeImages = now;
}
```

where cachedTimeImages is a property declared as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDateComponents *cachedTimeImages;
```

After each minute, I click the Mark Heap button in Instruments. Instruments says my heap is growing with the `NSDateComponents` object. What am I doing wrong in the above code?

Comment: Is the autorelease pool getting emptied on a regular basis?  Simply having an autorelease pool isn't sufficient.

Comment: Yes, in the method which calls saveCurrentlyCachedMinutes, there is an     NSAutoreleasePool new/drain.

Comment: Just for grins, try putting an autorelease pool IN the above method.  I'm guessing either your other pool isn't properly placed, or your heap growth is due to NSDateComponents being allocated elsewhere.

Comment: (Though there's also the possibility that your cachedTimeImages variable is being subsequently added to an NSArray or such and that's holding all the NSDateComponents objects.)

Comment: Adding an extra autorelease pool in the method didn't change the outcome :-( The property isn't being added to arrays or somesuch anywhere else.

Comment: (I'm vaguely recalling that there is/was a bug in iOS 6 related to leaks in NSCalendar, et al.  I tagged several such bugs/"features" with the `ios6-compatibility` tag, but TPTB kept deleting the tags, so there's no easy way to find them at this stage.)

Comment: OK thanks anyway, it's not a biggie anyway. I'll try and see what happens with the next iOS release.